# Checking if PDF is an image/OCR'd in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using VBA in Word to open up a bunch of PDF files (one by one), and look for some text. Some of the files I'm running across are actually images/not OCR'd. I'd like to just skip them, but I'm not sure what kind of check to do for that. On these files, it still "finds" the string, and gets to the part in my code I don't want it to process.

```
Dim pdfDoc As Word.Document
Dim ratingString As String
Set pdfDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=FSOFile.Path, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto)
Set ratingString = pdfDoc.Range

ratingString.Find.Execute FindText:="Evaluation Rating", MatchCase:=True

If ratingString.Find.Found = True Then
    'Somehow it gets to here when the pdf is an image
End If
```

Could someone suggest how to prevent images from 'passing' my check? Thanks!

Comment: A PDF can contain any combination of text and pictures. You wouldn't want to exclude everything that includes any picture at all. It would be difficult to distinguish between a PDF that contains an image and a PDF where too much text is an image. Word is not the best tool for this job.

Comment: What is happening with these documents? What does your code do right now? Does it throw an error?

Comment: When working with PDFs, I generally use the JavaScript and other processes built into Acrobat. Here's a page on Acrobat methods to check if a PDF is text (searchable): https://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2007/02/is_that_pdf_sea/ The Batch Process about halfway down the page should help you make an initial sort to discard the image PDFs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with word in my situation. It connects to a site, downloads a bunch of PDFs, and then goes through each one and grabs some text inside it for later processing. Sometimes it errors (like in this case where the pdf is an image), and sometimes I can even open the documents since pdfDoc is 'Nothing' (it won't even open the file for some reason), even though I can open it on my computer fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OCR'd PDF will also typically contain both the image of the original content and the OCR'd rendition behind it. And, depending on the quality of the OCR software and input image, the text you're after may or may not have been correctly rendered.

Try something along the lines of:

```
Dim pdfDoc As Word.Document
Set pdfDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=FSOFile.Path, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto)
With pdfDoc
  With .Range
    .Find.Execute FindText:="Evaluation Rating", MatchCase:=True
    If .Find.Found = True Then
      ' Process the found content, e.g.:
      MsgBox .Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
    End If
  End With
  .Close False
End With
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks!